# HLSL - organizing shaders and techniques and not getting lost

Tags: monogame, hlsl

I need help with organizing shaders in my game.

The game uses vertex and pixel shaders for texturing and lighting. Some objects are textured, other just colored, then there are several lighting algorithms - lightmaps, diffuse and specular lighting, some shadow generation which only some objects get, etc.

My first idea was to have one big, nice shader technique which can handle it all based on parameters. This was great to maintain (pseudo code to give idea):

```
float4 PixelShaderFunction(input)
{
    if (UseTexture)
        objectColor = tex2D(...)
    else
        objectColor = ObjectColor;

    if (UseAmbient)
        ...

    if (UseDiffuseLight)
        ...

    // etc...
}
```

However the performance was poor.

Then I created multiple techniques to avoid `if` branches, so every technique only uses what a particular object needs. So if the object doesn't accept shadows, there's no code for it there. If it doesn't make specular light, no code. Plus I grouped common functionality into functions. Like this (real code now):

```
float4 Textured_PixelShader(Textured_VsOut input) : COLOR0
{
    float4 lightLevel = 0;
    float4 objectColor = GetObjColorTex(input.TexUV);

    // calculate main table lighting
    PsAddTableLight(input.WorldPosition, input.Normal, lightLevel);

    // calculate cloth lighting
    PsAddClothLight(input.WorldPosition, input.Normal, lightLevel);

    // calculate fill light - do we need it?
    PsAddFillLight(input.Normal, lightLevel);

    // add ambient light
    PsAddAmbientLight(lightLevel);

    // apply light
    PsApplyDiffuseLight(lightLevel, objectColor);

    // add speculars
    PsAddSpecularBlurred(input.WorldPosition, input.Normal, objectColor);

    // final work
    return PsFinalize(objectColor);
}
```

The improvement in performance was massive.

However I'm getting lost in maintaining this shader. Every second day I need to add a new technique because there isn't yet a combination which does `texture + lightmap + this_kind_of_shadow + specular` or whatever I need. Some of them get names like this, other gets named by the object they are used for because there is only one object with such combination. And it's becoming a mess.

I have then two questions:

- Why cannot I have those `if` statements? I read a lot about how conditional execution hurts GPUs, but my ifs only depend on shader parameters which have same value for all rendered pixels (or verts). Why cannot they be fast? I really miss them.
- What is the best way to divide this code into different shaders / techniques / files. Are there any good standards or rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why cannot I have those if statements? I read a lot about how conditional execution hurts GPUs, but my ifs only depend on shader parameters which have same value for all rendered pixels (or verts). Why cannot they be fast? I really miss them.

Thoughts:

The main problem is here, that the compiler only sees a boolean expression and not the semantical information that your variable is a shader constant. It is only a special case and can become complex, if you for example use a more sophisticated boolean expression with functions, which only uses shader constants too. I think to prevent a lot of headaches of the shader compiler developers they choose to let the if be as general as it is.

Facts:

As stated in the [HLSL-Documentation for `if`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509610(v=vs.85).aspx), there are two modes of the if, either `flatten` or `branch`. With `flatten` the compiler rolls out both sides of the if, so they are computed first, and afterwards the result is taken from the right side. With `branch` only the right side is executed, as the boolean is evaluated first, but this mode can only be used if you don't use any gradient functions like tex2D, because they are dependent of neighbour fragments, and so need to be executed on each fragment and must not be skipped. In your case I'm pretty sure that you are using such functions, so the compiler chooses `flatten` for your ifs, resulting in a fully executed and slow shader.

> What is the best way to divide this code into different shaders / techniques / files. Are there any good standards or rules?

As far as I know there are no good standards, but I think engines like Unity or Unreal are a good spot to have a deeper look, how they are managing their shaders. The last time I looked into Unreal, they dynamically generated each shader once it is needed, so the shader code is generated from their shader builder, which then is compiled.

In my own little engine, I used a similar approach as you, but instead of dynamic branching, I'm using the preprocessor directives [`#if, #elif, #else, and #endif`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd607347(v=vs.85).aspx). If the engine encounters a needeed shaders, it sets the right defines and then compiles them on the fly with [`D3DCompile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd607324(v=vs.85).aspx). To prevent stuttering, I save the compiled shaders to disc and before compiling, I'm looking for the shader, if it has been compiled before.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems I cannot follow your way (dynamic compiling), because monogame doesn't support it, and even if it would it would be limited to some platforms only. But this is great and valuable answer which I mark as accepted - thanks.

Comment: And as for why `if` are slow - I am still not sure, but will do some retesting soon to verify performance slowdown. According to all sources it should be fast, as the `if` condition is same for all things rendered.